# Implement Color Graded Scale Using Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm at a loss of how to do this, how can I implement color graded conditional formatting using openpyxl:

[image]

How do I apply something like this to a given range?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be helpful: [Openpyxl Conditional Formatting](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formatting.html).
Base on that you could try:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import ColorScaleRule

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws.conditional_formatting.add('B1:B10', 
    ColorScaleRule(start_type='percentile', start_value=1, start_color='00FF0000',
        mid_type='percentile', mid_value=50, mid_color='00FFFF00',
        end_type='percentile', end_value=99, end_color='0000FF00'
    )
```

I don't know if they support "Lowest Value"  or "Highest Value", but you could try using those and omitting the `start_value` and  `end_value` inputs.